# redirecting to next page after submitting the data to database

Tags: php

I want to redirect the user to next page afte successfully submitting their information to the database. I am using redirect function like this

```
<?php
    $plan = @$_GET['plan']; // this is from url

?>


<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1"  onsubmit="return Validate();">
                <input type="hidden" name="plan" value="<?php echo $plan ?>"/>
    Company Name: 
        <input type="text" name="CompanyName" style="width:230px; height:20px;" /><br /><br />
    Company E-mail : 
    <input type="text" name="CompanyEmail" style="width:230px; height:20px;" /><br /><br />
     Company Contact <input type="text" name="CompanyContact" style="width:230px; height:20px;" /><br /><br />
     Company Address: <input type="text" name="CompanyAddress" style="width:230px; height:20px;" /><br /><br />
    Select Your Registration Type : <br /><br />
Trail: <input type="radio" name="RegistrationType" value="Trail" /><br />
                                     Paid<input type="radio" name="RegistrationType" value="Paid" /><br /><br />

     <input type="hidden" name="form_submitted" value="1"/> 
     <input type="submit" value="REGISTER" name="submit" />



</form> 
 <?php

     include('connect.php');

            If (isset($_POST['submit']))
            {
            $CompanyName = $_POST['CompanyName'];

            $CompanyEmail = $_POST['CompanyEmail'];
            $CompanyContact = $_POST['CompanyContact'];
            $CompanyAddress = $_POST['CompanyAddress']; 

            $RegistrationType = $_POST['RegistrationType'];
            $Plans = $_POST['plan'];
            $Status = "Active";


    $sql = "INSERT INTO ApplicationRegister (CompanyName, CompanyEmail, CompanyContact, CompanyAddress, RegistrationType, ApplicationPlan, ApplicationStatus, CreatedDate) VALUES ('$CompanyName', '$CompanyEmail', '$CompanyContact', '$CompanyAddress', '$RegistrationType', '$Plans', '$Status', NOW() )";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

if($plan == "trail")
{

header("Location: userRegister.php");
}
else
{
    header("Location : PaymentGateway.php");
}


            }
```

But its not redirecting anywhere, but its successfully submits the data.. Please suggest me where i am going wrong.

Comment: Your SQL is not very secure, you might want to research SQL Injection and how to avoid it

Comment: Whether you are getting any error or warning add error_reporting(E_ALL); on the top of the code and try

Comment: There is so much wrong in this code snippet. Sql injection, error suppersion, old mysql_* functions.... Don't use @GET. Use isset to say the least. You shouldn't suppers errors, you should solve them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use `header()` after you have sent anything to your the browser. In this instance all the HTML you have in the middle is sent first. Moving all your PHP to the top of the file should mean it works - with the added benefit of being easier to read!

```php
<?php
$plan = @$_GET['plan']; // this is from url
include('connect.php');

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $CompanyName = $_POST['CompanyName'];

    $CompanyEmail = $_POST['CompanyEmail'];
    $CompanyContact = $_POST['CompanyContact'];
    $CompanyAddress = $_POST['CompanyAddress'];

    $RegistrationType = $_POST['RegistrationType'];
    $Plans = $_POST['plan'];
    $Status = "Active";


    $sql = "INSERT INTO ApplicationRegister 
    CompanyName, CompanyEmail, CompanyContact, CompanyAddress, RegistrationType, ApplicationPlan, ApplicationStatus, CreatedDate) 
    VALUES 
    ('$CompanyName', '$CompanyEmail', '$CompanyContact', '$CompanyAddress', '$RegistrationType', '$Plans', '$Status', NOW() )";

    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    if ($plan == "trail") {
        header("Location: userRegister.php");
        exit();
    } else {
        header("Location : PaymentGateway.php");
        exit();
    }
}
?>


<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1"  onsubmit="return Validate();">
    <input type="hidden" name="plan" value="<?php echo $plan ?>"/>
    Company Name: 
    <input type="text" name="CompanyName" style="width:230px; height:20px;" /><br /><br />
    Company E-mail : 
    <input type="text" name="CompanyEmail" style="width:230px; height:20px;" /><br /><br />
    Company Contact <input type="text" name="CompanyContact" style="width:230px; height:20px;" /><br /><br />
    Company Address: <input type="text" name="CompanyAddress" style="width:230px; height:20px;" /><br /><br />
    Select Your Registration Type : <br /><br />
    Trail: <input type="radio" name="RegistrationType" value="Trail" /><br />
    Paid<input type="radio" name="RegistrationType" value="Paid" /><br /><br />

    <input type="hidden" name="form_submitted" value="1"/> 
    <input type="submit" value="REGISTER" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way, by including this in the start:

```
<?php
    if(mysql_query($query))
        header('Location: http://example.com/newurl/');
    else
        echo "Error!";
?>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just for a convention, make a habit of using `exit` after your `header()`.

```
<?php
header("Location: http://www.example.com/"); /* Redirect browser */

/* Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect. */
exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Only put your page path on which you want to redirect:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                                ADD CONTENT
                            </button>
                            <!-- Modal -->
                            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                <div class="modal-dialog">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Please Add Content</h4>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                <form role="form" action="" method="POST">
      <!-- YOUR HTML FORM GOES HERE--->
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"id="sub" onclick="SUBMISSION()" >Submit </button>
                            </fieldset>

             </form>
  <?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    SUBMISSION();
    }
function SUBMISSION()
{
 // UR CONNECTION ESTABLISHMENT CODE GOES HERE
  // SQL QUERY FOR INSERTION IN FIELDS

 echo"<script type=\"text/javascript\">
document.location.href='http://localhost/your file path/YOURPAGE.php'; // ur desired redirect page path where u want to go with recent submit data u can also in same page
</script>";

$conn->CLOSE();

}

?>

                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                    <!-- /.modal-content -->
                                </div>
                                <!-- /.modal-dialog -->


                            <!-- /.panel-body -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.panel -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
```